# What is the best process for updating sugarcrm?

Tags: sugarcrm

I have a client that has `SugarCRM 5.5.4` in production with many customizations. I tried updating `(5.5.4 > 6.1.0 > 6.2.5 > 6.2.6)` and had problems in `Studio (6.2.5)`, `ModuleLoader` and even `Updater (6.2.6)` after that.

Now I've set up a new `6.5.7` installation and updated all the modules to work properly in that.

What is the best way now to migrate the data from an old version of sugar into a new one?

I worked with Talend but it wasn't that effective (too much time lost). Now I just migrate the tables like this:

```
INSERT INTO 657.notes ( 
  `assigned_user_id`, `id`, `date_entered`, `date_modified`, `modified_user_id`, 
  `created_by`, `name`, `file_mime_type`, `filename`, `parent_type`, `parent_id`,
  `contact_id`, `portal_flag`, `embed_flag`, `description`, `deleted`  
)
SELECT 
  `assigned_user_id`, `id`, `date_entered`, `date_modified`, `modified_user_id`, 
  `created_by`, `name`, `file_mime_type`, `filename`, `parent_type`, `parent_id`,
  `contact_id`, `portal_flag`, `embed_flag`, `description`, `deleted`  
FROM `554`.notes
```

I was wondering how others do and what the best practice would be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work fine; note you'll probably want to do a Quick Rebuild and Repair afterwards to make sure the database is all correct.